# Estimate Total Disk Space for Ubuntu 22.04 and LAMP packages

Tags: 22.04, disk-usage

Will the $4 DigitOcean droplet (512MB RAM + 10GB SSD) suffice for a 250MB PHP app ?

I understand the Ubuntu 22.04 itself will come under 5 GiGs ? So having a Laravel app much under 1 GiG will do for a 10GB storage ?

How much disk-space will Ubuntu 22.04 with the server software (https://ploi.io/server-installation#what-software-gets-installed) take in total ? Is there any way to figure that out prior to setting up the server ?

Comment: I can write a 2kb PHP project that will easily consume several dozen gigabytes of memory. That said, I can also write an entire LMS in PHP that sips memory and never exceeds 28MB per HTTP request. What you’ll want to do is test the limits of your deployed system in a VM such as VirtualBox. Give the system 512MB RAM and see if it can perform. If it cannot, go up to 768, then 1GB, etc. The VM will be a decent approximation of what you might expect in the cloud (aside from processor speed, which is always faster locally).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)